# Check validation of access token in loopback

Tags: access-token, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is this a method in user model in loopback to check the access token is still valid or not?

If there isn't such method how can I create that?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the AccessToken.resolve can validate the access token by id

     AccessToken.resolve(req.headers.authorization, function(err, token){
       if(err){
          console.log(err);
       }else{
          console.log(token);
       }
    });
```